# Can cmx and non cmx ethernet cable be coupled

Tags: wiring, ethernet

Is it acceptable to use cmx rated cable outside and then switch over to non cmx inside with one of these?

It's residential for poe security cameras and less than 300 feet total in run lengths.

[image: coupler]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. CMX is only about the exterior rated jacket material. A better solution would be to terminate both cables to fixed jacks, and connect them with patch cords, rather than having floating couplers and plugs crimped onto solid cables like this, but this can work (it's just somewhat more prone to fail.)

Comment: Are you talking about something like an unpowered hub? I don't want to terminate cables if I don't have to and would like to use preterminated cabling. What term can I websearch if I understand you correctly?

Comment: If you are buying preterminated cabling, you're committed to the method you show. That will also require rather large holes to run the plugs on the preterminated cables through.  **cat5e wall jack** would be an appropriate search term, but evidently you don't want to...